# How do you send form data as a variable within a sentence to the clipboard with a button?

Tags: java, php, html, forms

I've been trying to figure out the answer to what I believe is a very simple question but have had no luck thus far. Unfortunately I'm not very well versed in html or java as of yet.

At my employment my team is faced with manually typing out a series of sentences that are always the same each time with the exception of one variable. These are required documentations and become rather monotonous and time consuming when manually entered each time. In addition to this- the computers are ancient and memory intensive scripts would be more bothersome than beneficial- even if it means more code I'm looking for the quickest, least intensive solution, that I can present to the whole team at once.

My objective is to create a series of forms and then have the variables inserted into pre-constructed sentences and copied as a whole to the clipboard all at once.

I can only create the forms successfully and have had no luck with either; A) posting the sentences with the variables into a text area so that it can be manually copied or B) the more preferred result of clicking a submit button to have it generate the pre-contructed sentences in the background unseen while including the variables and copying it all to the clipboard.

Essentially... I want something like this-

```
Name -----
Age-----
Gender-----
Job-----

SUBMIT
```

Upon clicking submit it would copy all the text below to the clipboard without displaying it-

Person of interest, $name, was recently added.
The person of interest works as a $job and has not recently undergone surgery.
$name is $gender and is currently $age.

I know this is possible although I have no idea how to actually achieve it. I thought at first I could just create the form data, attach it to a variable in php, echo the variable in sentences in a display:none environment then have it all copied with... no idea, maybe I was going to assign all of the echo'd sentences to yet another variable and then have the submit button copy the variable to the clipboard. Even just saying that is painfully inefficient. I need serious help on this guys =(

Comment: does not sound like a job for php, it is run server side, does not know that the user clipboard is.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say that maybe I had planned on using the php to echo the variables assigned from the forms, then take the echo'd sentences+variables all together and reassign that to a new variable and then use the java code to copy it? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851/Click-Its-Copied.htm something like that, I guess. More than the automatic copying I just need a way to at least post all of the form data into a text area, fitting in the variables into pre-contructed sentences that are generated with the button. The automatic copying can wait =(

Comment: its tagged (and you wrote) *java* but the link is javascript?

Comment: As you can see I can't even properly name things correctly yet.. an answer that I could copy and paste and adjust would be about the only thing I could manage at this point. I am not compensated for the endeavor as I'm actually just an underling who is also having to type out these ridiculously mundane sentences day in and day out. Computer security prevents running unauthorized executables and I would rather not lose my job- otherwise I am confident I could write it in BASIC lol

Comment: For what it is worth, html/javascript (although still a big blurry mess to me) is the only efficient way I can distribute the tool to the rest of the team without jeopardizing anyone. The documentation is an adaptation of a publicly released file that we type into a database. We were actually encouraged to type it all out somewhere (albeit even notepad.exe is prohibited to us) so I've been copying it to an html testboard and then trudging through to replace variables. I realized that I should just have it all as a form that I could submit, but I can't post the form data into sentences.

Comment: btw thank you AVD for the friendly edit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use $_SESSION variable with random string placeholders for variables.

```
$_SESSION['message']="Person of interest, <<name>>, was recently added.\n...."
```

When the form is submitted, just replace the placeholders with actual values into it, like:

```
$_SESSION['message']=str_replace('<<name>>',$_POST['name'],$_SESSION['message']);
```

Then, whenever you have to use the statement, you can use it as,

```
<textarea id='message'><?php echo $_SESSION['message'] ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I would upvote but unfortunately I can't yet I guess. I will see if I can toy around with this, and I'm sure you've laid the ground for further research on the commands, so I am thankful for that even if it doesn't turn out to be something that I could make work.

Comment: For some reason I am not able to display the executed php echo within the textarea- rather it just seems to be displaying the code. Is there a missing step? Or a solution to remedy that?

Comment: It won't get displayed if the file is an html file. php code is rendered only in .php files

Comment: Ahhh... then I guess that isn't the solution I need. Or that it could still be if I could find a different way of populating the text area. Or... if I avoid the text area all together by just pulling all the php variables into the javascript copy. Argh.